# Getting textarea's to be next to each other in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a div, and I have 2

```
<textarea>
```

tags inside. How do I get them to go next to each other instead of one on each row.

[JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/ya5xt59m/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can just do

```
.input-field-div{
   display:inline-block; 
}
```

```css
.thirdrow {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 10px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.input-field-div{
   display:inline-block; 
}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 thirdrow">
    <!-- Input Fields -->
    <!-- Player 1 Name Input Field -->
    <div class="input-field-div">
        <textarea id="input-player1-name" rows="1" placeholder="Player 1 Name"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- Player 2 Name Input Field -->
    <div class="input-field-div">
        <textarea id="input-player2-name" rows="1" placeholder="Player 2 Name"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```